# Incorporating algosigner chrome extension to React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to connect to the AlgoSigner chrome extension ( github [here](https://github.com/PureStake/algosigner/blob/develop/docs/dApp-integration.md#algosignerconnect) ) in my react project, but whenever I try to use the AlgoSigner methods, it always says that 'AlgoSigner' is not defined. How do I import it into my project? Following their instructions and cloning the repository into the root of my project doesn't work, unless I'm not doing it right. What should I include in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to keep in mind : -

1. Algosigner extension should be installed on the browser.
2. Once Algosigner is installed on the browser it gets injected into every page so you can use it like a global var.

Your case might be that either the extension is not installed or if the extension is already installed then you are not using that global var correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have more complicated setup. My project is typescript using [remix.run](https://remix.run/). I applied what Babita said above but I needed to do this:

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    AlgoSigner: any
  }
}
```

You may need to define the properties of `AlgoSigner` to help you with IntelliSense. I will update this if I do.

Hint: There is [another solution](https://github.com/fabrice102/algosigner-dapp-react-example) in a React project using [eslint no-undef](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) but it didn't work for me in a typescript project

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the window.AlgoSigner function.  The error will disappear.

Comment: Not sure why -vote.  This worked for me.  Thanks.  +1